# find the row with highest number of NA value in R

Tags: r, row, missing-data

I have datafrom

```
df
1 a c  NA NA
2 a a  a  NA
3 c NA NA NA
```

Firstly, I want to find which row has the highest number of NA value. I am also interested to find rows with the condition of having more than 2 NA values.
How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`na_rows = rowSums(is.na(df))` gives the count of NA by row. You can then look at `which.max(na_rows)` and `which(na_rows > 2)`.